# When is an operator acting on a space with periodic boundaries self-adjoint?

Tags: functional-analysis, quantum-mechanics, self-adjoint-operators

I found this discussion on Wikipedia regarding the self-adjointnes of the momentum operator on a bounded domain. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-adjoint_operator#Boundary_conditions

The problem discussed there is similar to one I am dealing with, except for the fact that there is an extra dimension in play. Concretely, I have a symmetric operator of the form:

$$T=A(x)\partial_x+B(x)$$

which should act on the set of square integrable functions $f:[0,1]\times [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ with doubly periodic boundary conditions: $f(0,y)=f(1,y)$ and $f(x,0)=f(x,1)$ for all $x,y\in [0,1]$. Is this operator self-adjoint for the right choice of the domain, like the momentum operator, or are there some complications arising in this case?

Comment: $A$ and $B$ need to be chosen so that $T$ is symmetric.

Comment: @KeithMcClary Yes, they are chosen as such (I didn't put the full expressions because they are quite lengthy; the symmetry condition is checked with maple). So symmetry is enough for it to be self-adjoint in this case?

Comment: I can't think of a proof or counterexample at the moment.

Comment: You say "The problem discussed there is similar to one I am dealing with, except for the fact that there is an extra dimension in play." I think the hard part is the non-constant coefficient $A(x)$. Can you answer the 1D question with non-constant coefficient $A(x)$?